# Send XMPP message with custom element in message stanza using SleekXMPP

Tags: python, xmpp, sleekxmpp

I'm developing a *XMPP bot* that will send/reply a message to the sender with a addition element as following

```
<message to="user1@example.com" from="user2@example.com">
  <my_element_1>foo</my_element_1> 
  <my_element_2>bar</my_element_2>
  <body>Hi!</body>
</message>
```

I've tried to used SleekXMPP `Object`, `Iq`, `Message` but not able to achieve the target. Beside, I also tried to use `send_message` method.

I'm not sure if my googling keyword is not correct but I'm not able to find any documentation or guide related to this. However, I did found guide that might be helpful for this related to plugin creation. Will be much appreciated if someone could help me on this.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just realised that my understanding is not correct. Technically, to achieve this, I just need to do the following.

```
# create XML for element 1
element1 = ET.Element('my_element_1')
element1.text = 'foo'

# create XML for element 2
element2 = ET.Element('my_element_2')
element2.text = 'foo'
```

If needed, I can simply add child for the xml.

```
child = ET.Element('child-key')
child.text = 'child-value'
media.append(child)
```

In the `Message` object, I would just append as following

```
msg = self.Message()
msg.appendxml(element1)
msg.appendxml(element2)
msg.send()
```

Comment: For those wondering what `ET` is, the source code for SleekXMPP's `stanzabase.py` says it's `from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET`. It's not `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET`.